# How can I find the column value that was modified latest from audit table using "left self exclusion join"?

Tags: sql, t-sql, outer-join

I have the following table design (it's immutable, and awful):

Table 1: "ids": id1, id2.

Maps each id1 to 1 or more id2 values.

Table 2 "audit": id2, timestamp, unique_id.

Maps each id2 to audit trail of its changes. unique_id is guaranteed to be unique for each row in the table

Goal: for each distinct value of id1; select ONE row; containing whichever single id2 value (among those mapped to id1 in table 1) was modified latest according to table 2.

I have tried doing the "left self exclusion join" approach outlined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068268/getting-highest-results-in-a-join) but couldn't quite figure out how to get it working. My query looked like:

```
select i1.id1, a2.id2
from   ids i1
right join audit a1 on i1.id2=a1.id2
left join ids i2 on i1.id1=i2.id1
left outer join audit a2 on i2.id2=a2.id2
where a1.timestamp < a2.timestamp
and a1.unique_id!=a2.unique_id
-- and a1.id2 is null
```

The problem is, this returns zero rows, because in the query (excluding last commented out line) **none of the rows have zero id2**, so I am guessing i got my outer join wrong.

## Where am I going wrong here?

Example DB fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5c45/4

```
CREATE TABLE ids (id1 int, id2 int)
CREATE TABLE audit (id2 int, timestamp int, unique_id int)

insert into ids values (1,11)
insert into ids values (1,12)
insert into ids  values (2,23)
insert into audit values (11,101,10000)
insert into audit values (11,104,10001)
insert into audit values (12,102,10002)
insert into audit values (12,103,10003)
insert into audit values (23,101,10004)
```

Expected result set from this data:

```
id1   id2   explanation
1     11    id2=11 last modified at 104, id2=12 at 103.
2     23    Only 1 row. That case tripped my query too.
```

Clarification: I'm aware that this problem can be solved via a correllated subquery without using left self exclusion join. I'm NOT interested in how to do that, I'm interested in what is wrong with my left self exclusion join query.

Comment: I would cordially request that no answers/comments amounting to "here's a subquery-only approach" are offered. My main goal is to understand why the "left self exclusion join" didn't work.

Comment: i not have certly if i have understood your question, but do you can test it removing the "right" direction on first join? Maybe it help you.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo - I did. No effect (matter of fact, original version had no "right" joins and this was my attempt to fix the issue)

Comment: need to see some data (text tables, not images)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - linked DB fiddle

Comment: used  - that's the whole complexity. I need to find - for a given id1 - which id2 was modified last. So, for ID1, we have two possibles, 11 and 12. Between them, 11 was last modified at 104 and 12 was last modified at 103, so id2=11 wins (for id1=1)

Comment: OK, got it now (revised my answer). I definitely needed data to looks at (thanks) and I used some column aliases to make it more meaningful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7b31/6)

```
CREATE TABLE ids (id1 int, id2 int)
CREATE TABLE audit (id2 int, timestamp int, unique_id int)

insert into ids values (1,11)
insert into ids values (1,12)
insert into ids  values (2,23)
insert into audit values (11,101,10000)
insert into audit values (11,104,10001)
insert into audit values (12,102,10002)
insert into audit values (12,103,10003)
insert into audit values (23,101,10004)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      audit1.*
FROM (
  select data.id1 as data_id, audit.id2 as fk, audit.timestamp, audit.unique_id
  from audit
  INNER JOIN ids data ON audit.id2 = data.id2
) as audit1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select data.id1 as data_id, audit.id2 as fk, audit.timestamp, audit.unique_id
  from audit
  INNER JOIN ids data ON audit.id2 = data.id2
  ) AS audit2 ON audit1.data_id = audit2.data_id 
             AND audit1.timestamp < audit2.timestamp
             AND audit1.unique_id <> audit2.unique_id
WHERE audit2.data_id is null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7b31/6/0)**:

```
| data_id | fk | timestamp | unique_id |
|---------|----|-----------|-----------|
|       1 | 11 |       104 |     10001 |
|       2 | 23 |       101 |     10004 |
```

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. It returned 3 rows not 2. I edited test data (as well as sample fiddle URL) into the question

Comment: Correct. However, I am trying to get 1 row per id1 value, NOT per id2 value (which is 1-N mapped from id1)

Comment: yes, the sample data has 11, 12 and 23 in id2 of the audit = 1 row per audit.id2

Comment: unless 11pm is messing with my head, 11 12 and 23 ad id2 values. not id1. Id1 values are 1 and 2. I added expected result set to question as well

Comment: I think I give in, the column naming is doing my head in.

Comment: Good news: I finally got it working. Bad news: i could have checked SO and see you arrived at same solution as myself (2 joins on each side of outer join). Good news: as I was working on my own, I actually figured out what my problem was conceptually, in the original query.

Answer (score 0):

The way the self exclusion join method in the linked SO question works is that you set up the left outer join from one table to itself so that every row that is not the row you want will have at least one link, while the row you want does not. So instead of

```
left outer join audit a2 on i2.id2=a2.id2
```

you need something like

```
left outer join audit a2 on a1.id2=a2.id2 AND a1.timestamp < a2.timestamp
```

What this means is every row that is not the highest timestamp for a given ID will link to at least one other a2 row, but the highest timestamp (the one you want) does not. Then you use the WHERE A2.id2 IS NULL clause to get rid of all the rows you don't want.

Note that as your number of items with the same id grows, the more intermediate data gets created (and ignored). Five items have 4 rows for the lowest timestamp, 3 for the next, etc. The size is factorial (n - 1), which can get quite large quickly.